# Horizontal slider with tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scrollbar

I need to combinate 2 scripts to get a tab based system with scrollbar on the bottom of the content. I combinated this ajax tabs:

http://www.crackajax.net/tabs.php

with this silder

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/

but when I open the slider's tab I can't move the slider. On the php page called content I put the slider where say as `if($_GTE['content']) == 1`, I know advanced php so I undersatnd everything in php but I don't really know jQuery and JavaScript so please help me with this.

NOTE: If i use only the slider in a separated file it works perfectly but when i paste it into the tabs system or include then the slider turns off and i cant use the slider button.. -.-

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#tabs

Comment: No, :) I want to select a tab for exemple the mac tab and then inside the tab there is a content part where the text is written, so then i don't want to change the tab with the slider, what i want is to slide the content from left to the right but only scroll the cintent wich is inside the tab called mac

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/66109476@N07/6021592464/ heres an exemple what i want you see? the tabs on the topand sliding the content with the slider

Comment: I 've made it but the slider doesn't move.. any suggestion why could happen tis?